# Date bug with excel vba OS X

Tags: excel, macos, vba

Since i updated to Yosemite, i think a weird bug appeared.

the Date function returns a date value with no year.

I tried changing regional settings but i can't seem to get anything.

i have 2014-05-31 in cell 1,1 Cells(1, 1).Value will return "-05-31"
However, if i use .Text instead of .Value i get the correct value.
Even the Date function doesn't work right

Anyone has a quick fix? My whole macro relies on dates

```
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value <> DateValue(Date + 1) Then
        If MsgBox("Error, blablabla", vbYesNo, "Confirm Entry") = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

yes I'm having the same problem as a very quick solution change region setting to US